# Cambiar tamaño de subviews en Cocoa app sin usar nib o constraints

Tags: macos

En una aplicación para OS X usando la API Cocoa **¿cómo se puede ajustar el tamaño de las subviews cuando el tamaño de la ventana es reajustado por el usuario?**

La UI es creada en programación sin usar Interface Builder ni constraints, porque la intención es usar esto como un widget que se pueda agregar fácilmente a cualquier aplicación Cocoa.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar algo de código para ver cómo estás creando las vistas, y qué cosas has intentado?

Comment: @MarcosCrispino Todo lo que tengo de momento es la llamada a `initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:screen:` en el metodo `init` de una subclase de `NSWindow`, allí creo un `NSTextView` que debe debe ocupar todo el area cliente y reajustarse automáticamente con el tamaño de la ventana.

Comment: Entonces deberías ver la propiedad `autoresizingMask` como te decía en la respuesta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero que leas la sección [Resizing Subviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-SW27) en la documentación de `NSView`.

En particular, si puedes usar `autoresizesSubviews` y `autoresizingMask` seguramente no sea muy difícil de hacer. En caso contrario, utilizando los métodos `-resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:` y `-resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:` de `NSView` deberías poder manejar el comportamiento de cada *subview* en particular.